# Why isn't ml5.js DoodleNet displaying the result of the image classification in the span element?

Tags: javascript, html, machine-learning, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a website that classifies drawings using ml5.js doodleNet pretrained model. However, I am not sure how to incorporate it into my code. After I click submit with my current code, the drawing in the canvas is captured as an image URL which is sent to the doodleNet model and it says the machine learning model classified it as            . How do I correctly change it so it shows the classification?

```
<div class="left" id="resultContainer" style="display: none;">
        <h1>Your Drawing</h1>
        <img id="Drawing" alt="Your Drawing" width="640" height="301.5">
        <h2>The Machine Learning Model classified it as <span id="classificationResult"></span></h2>
    </div>
        <button id="submitButton" class="button">Submit!</button>
        <button id="refreshButton" class="button">Restart</button>
    <script>
        var notEmpty = false;
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resize();
            document.addEventListener('mousedown', startPainting);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopPainting);
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', sketch);
            window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
        });

        const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function resize() {
            ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        }

        let coord = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        let paint = false;

        function getPosition(event) {
            coord.x = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            coord.y = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }

        function startPainting(event) {
            notEmpty = true;
            paint = true;
            getPosition(event);
        }

        function stopPainting() {
            paint = false;
        }

        function sketch(event) {
            if (event.type === 'click') {
            drawDot(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
            return;
        }

        if (!paint) return;
        ctx.beginPath();
            
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
            
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            
        ctx.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y);
        

        getPosition(event);
        
        ctx.lineTo(coord.x , coord.y);
            
        ctx.stroke();

        const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
        submitButton.addEventListener('click', submit);

        function captureBox() {
            var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas");
            return canvas1.toDataURL();
        }
        let doodleClassifier;
        let resultsDiv;
        let boxURL;
        function submit() {
            if (!notEmpty) {
                alert('Draw on the canvas');
                    return;
            }
            boxURL = captureBox();
            const drawing = document.getElementById('Drawing');
            drawing.src = boxURL;
            const submitButton=document.getElementById('submitButton');
            submitButton.style.display='none';
                
            const canvasContainer = document.querySelector('.box');
            const resultContainer = document.getElementById('resultContainer');
            canvasContainer.style.display = 'none';
            resultContainer.style.display = 'block';

            doodleClassifier=ml5.imageClassifier('DoodleNet',modelReady);
        }
        function modelReady(){
            doodleClassifier.classify(boxURL,gotResults);
        }
        function gotResults(error,results){
            if(error){
                console.error(error);
                return;
            }
            /*console.log(results);
            let content=`${results[0].label} ${nf(100*results[0].confidence,2,)}`
            resultsDiv.html(content)*/
            console.log(results);
    
            const classificationResultSpan = document.getElementById('classificationResult');
            const resultLabel = results[0].label;
            const resultConfidence = (results[0].confidence * 100).toFixed(2);
            classificationResultSpan.innerText = `${resultLabel} with ${resultConfidence}% confidence`;
        }
        const refreshButton = document.getElementById('refreshButton');
        refreshButton.addEventListener('click', refresh);

        function refresh() {
            window.location.href='/draw'
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I tried what was in the commented block but same result

Comment: Is this solved? If yes, share your solution (if possible) as an Answer.